# Issue migrating code from TensorFlow 1.x to Tensorflow 2.x using Keras's model class

Tags: python-3.x, keras, tensorflow2.x

I have a code running a "custom" model which seems it was constructed using "Eager Mode". When I try to run the model.predict() function, I got the following error

File "/home/jptalledo/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/version_utils.py", line 122, in disallow_legacy_graph
raise ValueError(error_msg)
ValueError: Calling `Model.predict` in graph mode is not supported when the `Model` instance was constructed with eager mode enabled. Please construct your `Model` instance in graph mode or call `Model.predict` with eager mode enabled.

The python code looks like this:

```
  def nn_predict(self, img):
        """Run model prediction to classify image as EV and return its probability"""
        
        img = cv2.resize(cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB), self.target_image_size).astype(np.float32) / 255.0
        img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=0)
    
        with self.tf_graph.as_default():
            predictions = self.nn_model.predict(img)
        return predictions
```

Where the issue resides on:   predictions = self.nn_model.predict(img)

Any advice how to enable Eager Mode?

Thanks

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue? I'm having a similar problem right now.

Comment: Yes. I need to rollback CUDA library.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by this answer? As i have a very similar problem (maybe you can check my most recent question?)